# How would I make the slider cover the full width and height of this page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Thanks in advance for reading and answering.

I am trying to get a slider to cover the full width and height of the page under the navigation bar. My problem is that I cannot seem to style an individual element in the div that has my slider without influencing the performance of the script. I tried setting the width/height to 100% but then it overflows despite the overflow hidden property.

Here is my code so far:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9864678

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You might get better responses by simplifying your gist into some code that can be posted in your question.  Sometimes its also helpful to create a "fiddle" on http://jsfiddle.net that demostrates the problem.

Comment: Something that may causing an issue is that you do have a **div** inside the **head** tags. Try moving it inside **body**. Also as @mjhm try using jsfiddle. **Update**: Try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ra3Fq/) Hope it's gonna help you and other people see your code running.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I wasn't aware of jsfiddle and will use it from now on - it's a wonderful tool! Moved the divs in the head tags and it's still giving me some trouble.

Comment: I also tried looking for another slider online and I made this out of it: http://jsfiddle.net/lewaabahmad/56grg/

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.slider ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It does not work. It makes the images incredibly large - over the dimensions of the browser. Thanks for your help though; I did not down vote you.